# How to handle Runtime error 13 with filter

Tags: vba, ms-access

I try to many times but failed to get rid of runtime error 13. It shows error in me.filter line. Help will be appreciated

```
private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim arg() As Variant
 
If Nz(Me.OpenArgs) = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
Else
 
    MsgBox (Me.OpenArgs)

    If Len(Me.OpenArgs) > 0 Then

    arg = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")
    Me.Filter = "[lab book]=' " & "arg(0)" & "" And "[starting Page]='" & arg(1) & "'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
    End If
    

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: "arg(0)" should not be in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - and Page is numeric, I guess:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim arg() As Variant
 
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then

        MsgBox (Me.OpenArgs)

        arg = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")
        Me.Filter = "[lab book] = '" & arg(0) & "' And [starting Page] = " & arg(1) & ""
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If    

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much for you support but this one still show the run time error 13.   this is the first part of code                                                                                                        
 Private Sub btnopensearchform_Click()
Dim strArgs As Variant
bokref = Nz(Me.txtbookref)
startpage = Nz(Me.starting_Page)


If bokref <> "" Then
    strArgs = bokref & "|" & startpage
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmsearchbybook"
    DoCmd.OpenForm ("frmRevEntry"), , , , acFormEdit, OpenArgs:=strArgs
   
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub

Comment: Double-check `Me.OpenArgs` and study `Filter`: `MsgBox Me.Filter`.

Comment: Gustav Accidentally left a "" in his filter String.  That is why that part of the solution didn't work

Comment: @mazoula: No, it is only to indicate that the filter expression is complete. But there was a typo, now corrected.

Comment: sorry, I thought I had found the correct typo

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
'an array can be assigned to a variant, but you cannot assign to an array
'Spit returns an array of strings
  Dim Arg As Variant 'so make Arg a variant instead of an array of variants
  
 Dim strsql As String 'combining sql strings is very error prone.  When debugging print them
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        'MsgBox (Me.OpenArgs)
        Arg = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|") 'So, now Arg holds the array of strings returned by split
      
        
  strsql = "[lab book] = '" & Arg(0) & "' And [starting Page] = " & Arg(1)
  Debug.Print strsql
'Based on my dummy data: [lab book] = 'science' And [starting Page] = 5

'It is important to wrap your text arguments in apostrophes when you combine them into the sql string or pass them already wrapped 
'So check the datatypes in the table or query you are searching
        Me.Filter = strsql
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If
End Sub
```